# Car dies suddenly power at all

Tags: engine, electrical, starting, nissan, frontier

Today I was driving my BF's 2003 Nissan Frontier when suddenly it dies. No power, everything died. No hazard lights either. I tried popping the clutch to get it started and nothing.

I parked it in median and raised the hood. The battery was just replaced so I checked the connections and all was fine. I looked through the wiring and all seemed fine. About an hour goes by and then I hear the hazards come on so I decide to try to start the truck.

It turns over no problem so I drive it home, no problems whatsoever. I ask my BF to take me to the train. Enroute driving, he turns on the headlights and boom, it did it again.

He tried popping the clutch and it wouldn’t turn over. Just bog no power at all so we coasted off freeway and parked it. It has been over an hour and still no power. If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful because I’m at a loss.

It sounds electrical to me but maybe it could just be the alternator and battery. It’s a new battery so I don’t know any ideas. I’m open ears.

Comment: Is there anything electrical that you can get to work when it is in this state?  Knowing exactly what works and what doesn't can make it a lot easier for us to trace.

Comment: Does the engine turn over, or is the whole thing just dead?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Two things 1) What was the reason for battery replacement in the first place? 2) I sounds like it's a battery connection issue, but don't know for sure.

Comment: I've never heard of the "popping clutch" method of starting.  What do you mean by this?

Comment: @jwh20 The OP means letting the clutch pedal up while the car is moving so that the momentum of the car turns the engine instead of using the starter.  Just a strange name for it.

Comment: @jwh20 "pop the clutch" is a pretty standard term here in the US. Of course, since so few cars are sold with manual transmissions here, not many know the term any more and even fewer know how to do it.

Comment: @FreeMan I know what a clutch is and I have a car, 2008 Mini Cooper S, with one.  But "popping the clutch" to me means revving up the engine and then quickly releasing the clutch to make a quick start or skid the tires.  My trouble is how is this related to trying to star the car.  I believe the term for what we're talking about is a "bump start" or a "push start".  Impossible for most automatic cars but possible for SOME manual cars.  Some won't start because there is not enough electrical power to get the electronics running.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a loose main ground.  As the vehicle heats up the bolt expands and the connection gets weak, then the vehicle shuts off.  Follow the ground wire from the battery and ensure the frame location it bolts to is indeed tight.  Also make sure the battery connections are clean and tight.